# Search and Compare rows of two tables

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to find the same values in two different tables 
Lets say table1 attributes are: id,name,attendance and table2 : id,num_of_abs

I need to identify which values in the id column of table 1, are the same in the id column of table 2. And then display a message if the id value of table also exist in the id column of  table 2
so far i was able to write the following code :

```
$myData = mysql_query( $sql,$con);
$mysecData = mysql_query( $sqll,$con);
while($abs=mysql_fetch_array($mysecData))  {
  switch ($students=mysql_fetch_array($myData)) {
  case $abs['id'] == $students['Id'] :
    echo $students['Id'];
    break;
  default:
    echo "id is not the same";
}
```

the code is working only if the values are located in the same row of each table. If the values exist in both tables, but are not in the same row then the message "id is not the same " it shows up. Does anybody have any idea about how to fix this please ?

Thanks

Comment: I can't really understand what you're looking for, but you're almost certainly better off making a single SQL query to do what you're looking for, rather than doing the checks yourself. Let your database take care of doing the work for you.

Answer (score 0):

If you join the data from the 2 tables than you will have the matching records on the id column. That would be the simplest way to get the matching records from both tables. Here's an example based on the limited information in the post:

```
SELECT t1.id, t1.name, t1.attendance, t2.id, t2.num_of_abs
FROM table1 AS t1
JOIN table2 AS t2
ON t1.id = t2.id
```

I hope that helps get you in the right direction.